# Why doesn't work nuGet packages on my computer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package

I've tried to install libraries, but I get this message, when I try to use the dll file. 
"There are no components in ... example.dll that can't be placed on the toolbox."

I've been using Visual Studio 2017, and C# and of course, I made WPF application projects. I recieve this message every time, when I want to use the dll file. 
Why?

Comment: So you downloaded the dll, added a reference of the dll to your project and added by `using` the right namespace of the dll  to your project?

Comment: I followed theese instructions:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7MGaf8YW6s

Comment: I cant watch this video now, but just do what i told you. Right click on references, then add a reference and choose your `dll`. Then in your C# project on the top, where all the `using` assignments are placed, add `using [the namespace of your dll, Intellisense does suggest it as well];`